# reactJS: does initial state shape need to be defined?

Tags: reactjs

It feels cumbersome to define the initial state shape (with all its possibly nested values) before fetching the state from something that would set it anyway. I am wondering if I need to set the initial state shape or if there is some way around it.

```
this.state = {}
```

if I have this state and then I have a JSX object that tries to read `state.post` it would fails with `cannot read property "posts" of undefined`

```
<PostDiv post={this.state.post} />
```

is there a way to avoid defining the initial state shape, but also avoiding the error? I know I can do this...

```
{ this.state.post && <PostDiv post={this.state.post} /> }
```

but that ends up being just as verbose as defining the initial state shape that I am trying to avoid.

Comment: I you don't define it initially then there's no simple way around an error where a component tries to access a part of the state before it's loaded. As you've discovered, you either gotta set the initial state shape, or do conditional rendering which checks for that state property

Comment: thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define state as:

```
this.state = {};
```

and tries to access `this.state.post` it will not throw any error at this place because state is defined and `this.state.post` will be undefined.

Check this snippet:

```js
let state = {};

console.log('post = ', state.post);
```

But if you try to access any property of `this.state.post` then it will throw this error:

> cannot read property "posts" of undefined

I think in your case this error is coming from component `PostDiv`, where you are trying to access some value of post props passed from parent.

So possible solutions are:

1.Define the initial value of post in state variable.

2.Use conditional rendering

3.Write it like this:

```
<PostDiv post = { this.state.post || {} } />
```

By the last one if post exist then it's value get passed otherwise the default value will be `{}`.